# duvida sore o each JQUERY

Tags: html, jquery

estou quebrando a cabeça e não consigo achar o problema tenha uma tabela que é criada dinamicamente quando faço a varredura ele aparece a posição 0 como nulo e depois disso começa a aparecer normal

tela HTML
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

criação da linha na tabela

```
    var id = 1;


function criar_linhaGrid() {

    var dados = {
        Codigo: $("#txt_codigo").val(),
        Descricao: $("#txt_descricao").val()

    };

    // verificar se o códigoInterno da conversao foi digitado
    if (dados.Codigo != "") {


        $("#grid_cadastro > tbody").append(
         "<tr class = 'dadosConversao'>" +
        "    <td class='id'>" + dados.id + "</td>" +
        "    <td class='codigo'>" + dados.Codigo + "</td>" +
        "    <td class='descricao'>" + dados.Descricao + "</td>" +
        "    <td <a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-Excluir' role='button'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>  Excluir</a>" + "</td>" +
        "</tr>"
        )

        $("#modal_incluir").parents('.bootbox').modal('hide');

        $("#txt_codigo").val("");
        $("#txt_descricao").val("");

       id = id + 1;

    } 

};
```

HTML

```
                                        <div id="cabecalho_grid" class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <table id="grid_cadastro" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>ID</th>
                                                        <th>Código</th>
                                                        <th>Descrição</th>
                                                        <th>Ação</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                              <tbody>

                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
```

JQUERY para passar por ajax as listas da minha view

```
  $("#btnIncluirProduto").click(function () {


    var arrayConversao = $('.id');
    var listaConversao = new Array();
    $('#grid_cadastro tr').each(function (index) {

        listaConversao.push({
                   IDConversao: index,
                    Codigo: $(this).find('.codigo').text(),
                    Descricao: $(this).find('.descricao').text()

                });

                return listaConversao;
    });


});
```

no meu controller

```
        [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult SalvarProdutos(DTO.Produtos todas_listas)
    {


        // Falta Incrementar
        return View();


    }
```

imagem do controller inserido 2 registros pelo modal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso porque seu seletor do `each` está pegando todas as `tr`s, inclusive a primeira que é apenas o cabeçalho da tabela, onde não contém as classes que você captura, portanto o resultado do índice `0` será nulo ou undefined.

Para evitar a primeira linha da tabela, use o método `.not(":first")` que a primeira linha da tabela será ignorada:

```
$('#grid_cadastro tr').not(":first").each(function (index) {...
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado resolveu o meu problema

Comment: Amigo DVD estou fazendo em outro lugar o each e agora começou a salvar a primeira linha Nulo mesmo com o .not.
    $('#grid_Servico tr').not(":first").each(function () {

Comment: Eu teria que ver como está fazendo. Talvez seja interessante abrir uma nova pergunta.